# error: use of deleted function?

Tags: c++, tree

I am currently trying to implement a simple btree, but seem to have run into an issue here..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct element
{
    int x;
    int y;
    element (int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};

int sum(element key)
{
    return key.x + key.y;
}

struct node
{
    element key;
    node *child_left;
    node *child_right;
};


class tree{

    void insert(element key);
    void insert(element key, node* leaf);
    node* root;
    tree()
    {
        this->root = NULL;
    }
};

void tree::insert(element key){
    if(this->root != NULL){
        insert(key, this->root);
    }else{
        this->root = new node;
        this->root->key.x = key.x;
        this->root->key.y = key.y;
        this->root->child_left = NULL;
        this->root->child_right = NULL;



    }
}


void tree::insert(element key, node* leaf){
    if(sum(key) < sum(leaf->key)){
        if(leaf->child_left != NULL){
            insert(key, leaf->child_left);
        }else{
          leaf->child_left = new node;
          leaf->child_left->key.x = key.x;
          leaf->child_left->key.y = key.y;
          leaf->child_left->child_left = NULL;
          leaf->child_left->child_right = NULL;
        }
    }else if(sum(key) >= sum(leaf->key)){
        if(leaf->child_right != NULL){
            insert(key, leaf->child_right);
        }else{
            leaf->child_right = new node;
            leaf->child_right->key.x = key.x;
            leaf->child_right->key.y = key.y;
            leaf->child_right->child_left = NULL;
            leaf->child_right->child_right = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Somet"<< std::endl;

}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/0InxxBLt59PFVppt

Which gives me error message:

```
Start
prog.cc: In member function 'void tree::insert(element)':
prog.cc:49:20: error: use of deleted function 'node::node()'
   this->root = new node;
                    ^~~~
prog.cc:26:8: note: 'node::node()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct node
        ^~~~
prog.cc:26:8: error: no matching function for call to 'element::element()'
prog.cc:14:5: note: candidate: 'element::element(int, int)'
     element (int x, int y)
     ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:14:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
prog.cc:10:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr element::element(const element&)'
 struct element
        ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cc:10:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr element::element(element&&)'
prog.cc:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cc: In member function 'void tree::insert(element, node*)':
prog.cc:66:28: error: use of deleted function 'node::node()'
     leaf->child_left = new node;
                            ^~~~
prog.cc:76:28: error: use of deleted function 'node::node()'
    leaf->child_right = new node;
                            ^~~~
1
Finish
```

I am not sure I understand why this is causing problems... So some explanations would be appreciated, does structs (and classes) by itself have a default constructor? so why is it complaining?

Comment: @George Sorry for me asking.. where exactly is it saying that. 
I am bit rusty on my c++ part, but something so simple such as this seems to confuse me a lot?

Comment: Removed my comment because it's in tobi's answer anyway. Basically the only constructor that exists for `element` is `element::element(int,int)`, if you hadn't provided a ctor then C++ would've marked `element::element()` in for you. When you create a `node`, you'd also be trying to create an `element` using `element` s default ctor, which doesn't exist so the code is ill-formed..

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor of `node` is deleted, because `element` has none (thats btw exactly what the error message is trying to tell you ;). There is no compiler generated default constructor for `element` because you provided your own constructor (which is not a default constructor, ie you cannot call it without arguments). Either write a default constructor for `node` that passes parameters to the `element` constructor:

```
node() : key(element(1,2)) {}
```

or one for `element`:

```
element(int x=0,int y=0) : x(x),y(y) {}
```

In the latter case, a default constructor for `node` can and will be generated by the compiler because it is really just this:

```
node() {}
```