# Use of deleted function?

Tags: c++, constructor

This is my int main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "celle.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cell a(1,9,true);
    grid A;
    return 0;}
```

I'm trying to implement a list of cells, but the compiler reports this error to me:

> |10|error: no matching function for call to 'cell::cell()'|
>
> |52|error: use of deleted function 'List_node::List_node()'|
>
> |139|error: use of deleted function 'List_node::List_node()'|

The linked_list.h code:

```
    template <class T>
    class Linked_list;
    
    template <class T>
    class List_node{
        friend class Linked_list<T>;
     private:
        T _value;
        List_node<T> * _pPrev;
        List_node<T> * _pNext;
    };
    
    template <class T >
    class Linked_list : public Linear_list<T, List_node<T>*>{
     public:
        typedef typename Linear_list<T, List_node<T>*>::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename Linear_list<T, List_node<T>*>::position position;
    
        Linked_list();
        ~Linked_list();
        void create();
        bool empty() const;
        value_type read(position) const;
        void write(const value_type &, position);
        position begin() const;
        void erase(position);
        void insert(const value_type &, position);
        };
    
     private:
        List_node<T> * _pHead;
        int _length;
    };
    
    template <class T>
    Linked_list< T >::Linked_list() {
        _pHead = new List_node<T>;
        _pHead->_pNext = _pHead;
        _pHead->_pPrev = _pHead;
        _length = 0;
    }
    
    template< class T >
    Linked_list< T >::~Linked_list(){
        while(!empty())
            erase(begin());
        delete _pHead;
    }
    
    template< class T >
    void Linked_list< T >::create(){
        if (empty())
                _length = 0;
    }
    
    template< class T >
    bool Linked_list< T >::empty() const {
        return(_pHead == _pHead->_pNext);
    }
    
    template< class T >
    typename Linked_list< T >::position Linked_list< T >::begin() const {
        return (_pHead->_pNext);
    }
    
    template< class T >
    typename Linked_list< T >::value_type
    Linked_list< T >::read(position p) const {
        if (!end(p))
            return(p->_value);
    }
    
  template< class T >
  void Linked_list< T >::write(const value_type &a, position p) {
        if (!end(p))
        p->_value = a;
    }
    
  template< class T >
  void Linked_list< T >::insert(const value_type &a, position p){
        position t = new List_node<T>;
        t->_value = a;
        t->_pNext = p;
        t->_pPrev = p->_pPrev;
        p->_pPrev->_pNext = t;
        p->_pPrev = t;
        _length++;
    }

template< class T >
void Linked_list< T >::erase(position p){
    if (!empty() && !end(p)){
        p->_pPrev->_pNext = p->_pNext;
        p->_pNext->_pPrev = p->_pPrev;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

The celle.h code:

```
#include "linked_list.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

class grid;

class cell{
public:
    friend class grid;
    cell(int x,int y, bool viva){
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;
        this->viva=viva;
    }
    ~cell(){};

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    bool viva;
};

class grid{
public:
    grid();
    grid(int,int);
    ~grid(){};
    void insert (cell &);
    void remove (cell &);
    void moveLeft (int x, int y);
    void moveRight (int x, int y);
    void moveDown (int x, int y);
    void moveUpper (int x, int y);
    bool Sorrounded (int x, int y);
    void RemoveSorrounded ();

private:
    Linked_list<cell> cells;
    int rig;
    int col;
};

grid::grid(){
    rig=5;
    col=5;
}

grid::grid(int r, int c){
    rig=r;
    col=c;
}

/*void grid::insert (cell &k){
    if(k.viva){
        cells.insert(k,cells.begin());
    }
}*/
```

How could I solve it? Why do you tell me that the node constructor has been implicitly deleted?
I'm going crazy, sorry if I copied the whole code to you

Comment: the compiler only creates a default constructor when you do not declare a constructor. What do you want to happen when a `cell` is constructed but no parameters supplied? How do you want to initialize the members in that case?

Comment: Did you check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704900/error-use-of-deleted-function)

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a `Linked_list` with type `cell`, this implies that `List_node` has a type `cell`. In your `List_node`, you have `T _value;`, which stores a value for the `cell`. However, `cell` does not have a default constructor, since you defined it's constructor as `cell(int,int, bool)`. This implicitly deletes the default constructor in `List_node`. In your `insert` method, for your `Linked_list`, you do `position t = new List_node<T>;`, which calls its default constructor, which doesn't exist.

A simple way to fix this, is to have a `List_node` constructor which takes in a value by reference of type `T`, which is used to constructor by copy the `T` it needs. Something like this:

```
List_node( const T& value ) : _value(value) {}
```

Then in your insert method, you would have:

```
position t = new List_node<T>( a );
// t->_value = a; // not needed anymore
```

The more complex way is to use `forward_args` for in place construction. But in your code, a simple copy is sufficient.